# How to get a particular Index from a shuffled array

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've been working on a quiz app using NextJs and after figuring out how to work around the hydration issue in Nextjs, Now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to keep track of a value in the array.

```js
export default function quiz({ questions }) {
  const link = `https://the-trivia-api.com/api/questions`;

  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const [quizData, setQuizData] = useState(questions);
  const [numbering, setNumbering] = useState(1);
  const [initialRenderComplete, setInitialRenderComplete] = useState(false);
  
  console.log(quizData[number].correctAnswer);

  const oldArray = [...quizData[number].incorrectAnswers, quizData[number].correctAnswer];
  oldArray.push(quizData[number].correctAnswer); //Here I pushed the correct answer and incorrect answer into a single array.
  const newArray = [...new Set(oldArray)]; // 'newArray' is the new array containing all the four options.

  const increase = () => {
    setNumber(number + 1);
    setNumbering(numbering + 1);
  };
  const decrease = () => {
    setNumber(number - 1);
    setNumbering(numbering - 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setInitialRenderComplete(true);
  }, []);

  if (!initialRenderComplete) {
    return null;
  } else {
    newArray.sort(() => (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1)); // Here i shuffled the newArray, So the correct and incorrect answer is shuffled.
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <div className={styles.profile}>
          <div className={styles.mainProfile}>
            <div className={styles.profilePic}>
              <img src={image} alt="img" />
            </div>
            <h2>{state} </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.main}>
          <h2>
            {numbering}. {questions[number].question}{" "}
          </h2>
          <div className={styles.list}>
            <ul className={styles.list1}>
              <div className={styles.flex}>
                <h3>A. </h3>
                <button>
                  <li>{newArray[1]} </li>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className={styles.flex}>
                <h3>B. </h3>
                <button>
                  {" "}
                  <li> {newArray[0]} </li>
                </button>
              </div>
            </ul>

            <ul className={styles.list2}>
              <div className={styles.flexOption}>
                <h2>C. </h2>
                <button>
                  <li>{newArray[3]}</li>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className={styles.flexOption}>
                <h2>D. </h2>
                <button>
                  <li>{newArray[2]} </li>
                </button>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.btnStyle}>
            <button onClick={decrease} className={styles.prev}>
              Previous{" "}
            </button>
            <button onClick={increase} className={styles.next}>
              Next{" "}
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//Here is my Api Call
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const data = await Axios.get("https://the-trivia-api.com/api/questions");

  // const data = req;
  const initialData = data.data;
  return {
    props: {
      // question: data.data[indexing],
      questions: initialData,
    },
  };
};
```

Now I'm stuck on how to keep track of which is the correct or incorrect Option onClick of the button, I figured I could maybe keep track of the index of the correct answer in the array but I don't think it would work and I can't figure out how to do it, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You could simply store the `quizData[number].correctAnswer`'s `id` in some variable, which you can check against when an answer has been selected

Comment: @bitDaft Yeah i'm going to try something along this line....Thank you